# Expression type is ambiguous without more context

Tags: closures, swift3

I am trying to migrate 3rd party lib (expanding collection by Ramotion) to swift 3.
And I am pointing some bottleneck.

I have this struct:

```
struct ConstraintInfo {
  var attribute: NSLayoutAttribute = .left
  var secondAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute = .notAnAttribute
  var constant: CGFloat = 0
  var identifier: String?
  var relation: NSLayoutRelation = .equal
}
```

This operator with some overloads:

precedencegroup ComparisonPrecedence {
    associativity: left
    higherThan: LogicalConjunctionPrecedence
}

```
infix operator >>>- : ComparisonPrecedence

func >>>- <T: UIView> (left: (T, T), block: (_: inout ConstraintInfo) -> ()) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
  var info = ConstraintInfo()
  block(&info)
  info.secondAttribute = info.secondAttribute == .notAnAttribute ? info.attribute : info.secondAttribute

  let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: left.1,
                                  attribute: info.attribute,
                                  relatedBy: info.relation,
                                  toItem: left.0,
                                  attribute: info.secondAttribute,
                                  multiplier: 1,
                                  constant: info.constant)
  constraint.identifier = info.identifier
  left.0.addConstraint(constraint)
  return constraint
}
```

And this method in UIView extension:

```
func addScaleToFillConstratinsOnView(_ view: UIView) {
    [NSLayoutAttribute.left, .right, .top, .bottom].forEach { attribute in
        (self, view) >>>- { $0.attribute = attribute } // this line is erroring
    }
  }
```

Error says:

> "'>>>-' produces 'NSLayoutConstraint', not the expected contextual result type 'Void' (aka '()')"

I changed erroring line to

```
var _: NSLayoutConstraint = (self, view) >>>- { $0.attribute = attribute }
```

And now I am getting:

> Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context

Also, if I write:

```
$0.attribute as! NSLayoutAttribute = attribute as! NSLayoutAttribute
```

I am getting immutability error.

What am I missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I solved it this way:

```
[NSLayoutAttribute.left, .right, .centerY].forEach { attribute in
      _ = (view, collectionView) >>>- {
        var _: ConstraintInfo = $0
        $0.attribute = attribute
        }
}
```